# An Identically Zero Function

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ and $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\,\cos(nx)\,dx =0$ for all $n\geq0$, then show that $f$ is identically $0$ on $[0,\pi]$.
I have been trying some approximation, but to no avail. Thanks for any help.
Sorry,I had to again edit the problem.Actually the source of the problem gave me the false impression.Thanks everyone for your help and patience.

Comment: Your original post had $\sin nx$, but now has $\sin nx$. This changes the question and makes the answers look incorrect. Let the people who answer know when you do this, please.

Comment: how about $f(x)=sin(x)$.

Comment: True only is $f$ is even!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$g(x):=f\bigl(|x|\bigr)\qquad(0\leq|x|<\pi)\ .$$
Then $g\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, and
$$\hat g(n):={1\over 2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(x)e^{-in x}\ dx={1\over 2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(x)\bigl(\cos(nx)-i\sin(nx)\bigr)\ dx=0\quad \forall n\in{\mathbb Z}\ ,$$
which means that $\hat g=0\in L^2({\mathbb Z})$. According to $L^2$-Fourier-theory this implies  that  $g=0\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$; and as $f$ is supposed continuous,
we may conclude that $f(x)\equiv0$ on $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true. Take $f(x) = \cos(x)$ as a counterexample (you will always integrate an odd function and hence get zero).

Comment: Note true. You want $\sin x$, rather.

Comment: I believe the question was edited after I wrote the answer. =|

Comment: Yes, I have commented.

Answer (score 1):

For your original question, $f(x)=cos(x)$ which is orthogonal to all sine's but not identically zero.

So I guess you wanna also include $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) cos(nx) dx=0$ as another condition.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.I have edited.

Comment: @Ester, you may want to include both sine and cosine in your conditions. Those gives an orthogonal basis for Fourier expansion.